# Visual Studio build error “This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms": What triggers this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, fips

I am administering a set of Jenkins build projects that are now getting the error “This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms" from a new MSBuild project.  What attribute of a project triggers this?

I have seen elsewhere that there are a number of potential ways to 'fix' the error, i.e., adding an attribute '`<enforceFIPSpolicy enabled="false"/>`' to msbuild.exe.config, setting some Enable field to 0 in the registry.  I will try those, but that is not what I'm asking here.

My build machine has dozens of  Visual Studio C Sharp projects that have worked just fine.  Adding a new one is triggering this error, and it is not obvious to me what property this project has that the other projects that have built for months - without tweaking msbuild.exe.config - do not have.

What attribute or property of a project makes this error occur?

Comment: The new project is not using the NIST certified FIPS compliant .Net classes for cryptography. Introduced in .Net Framework 3.5, their names all end with CryptoServiceProvider.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I think that means I would find references to classes related to encryption.  When I open the project, I see references to things like Microsoft.CSharp, Microsoft.Office.Core, Microsoft.VisualBasic, a bunch of System. classes, and something called VBIDE, but nothing that stands out as being related to encryption.

Comment: I also find that the "<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>" solution is not working for me.